# Sort queryset with float values by specific order (like software version)

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and I would like to get your help in order to sort my queryset as I would like. My queryset gets list of versions from a model.

This is my queryset:

```
def actual_edition():
    return MyModel.objects.values_list('version', flat=True).filter(smt__isnull=False, published=True).order_by('version').first()
```

It gives me:

```
<QuerySet ['10.0', '9.10', '9.8', '9.9']>
```

But I would like to handle my queryset in order to display the result in this order:

```
<QuerySet ['9.8', '9.9', '9.10', '10.0']>
```

version field is a CharField in my model (I can't update this one to FloatField for example).
I don't find a way to do that with Django. Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your problem is that you don't really want them in float order, because numerically 9.10 < 9.9. Version numbers like this are really sequences of integers. Convert each version number using `[int(i) for i in mynumber.split(".")]` and compare the results.

Comment: @BoarGules Could you give a little example with comparison according to your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct syntax to do that:

```
def actual_edition():
    x = list(MyModel.objects.values_list('version', flat=True).filter(smt__isnull=False, published=True).order_by('version'))
    x.sort(key=lambda s: list(map(int, s.split('.'))))
```

it gives me:

```
# Before sort
['10.0', '10.1', '9.10', '9.8', '9.9']
# After sort
['9.8', '9.9', '9.10', '10.0', '10.1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using postgres you can make use of `string_to_array`. This [question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74283/how-to-order-by-typical-software-release-versions-like-x-y-z) solves the SQL portion of it.

For Django you'd need a custom `Func`:

```
from django.db.models import Func
class StringToArray(Func):
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '.')"
    function = 'string_to_array'
```

Then your QuerySet would look like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    smt__isnull=False,
    published=True,
).annotate(
    version_array=StringToArray('version'),
).order_by('version_array').values_list('version', flat=True).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a lambda function?

If s is a list of strings of floats, then

s.sort (key = lambda x: float(x))

should sort the way you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're storing version numbers, have you thought about using a lexicographic sort instead?  If you store the numbers with zero padding, you'd get the answer you're looking for with the exact filter you're already using (i.e., `['09.08', '09.09', '09.10', '10.00']`)

Comment: I know, but I haven't the choice. If the version is 9.8, I should be 9.8 and not 9.08 unfortunately :/